# double pointer question in C (single pointer for next, but double pointer for prev)

Tags: c, pointers

In the code of `table.h` for mysql. There are the following code

```
typedef struct st_table_share  
{
    ...  
    struct st_table_share * next,       /* Link to unused shares */  
      **prev;
```

in the text book, we usally have

```
sometype *next, *prev;
```

but here it use `**prev` instead of `*prev`. What the reason to use double pointer for `prev`?

Comment: Perhaps if you check out where it's used in code, you'll see why...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not pointing to the previous structure, as next is, it's pointing to the pointer that's pointing to this structure.

The benefit of doing this is that it can point to either the 'next' member of the preceding structure, or it can point to the actual head pointer itself - in the case where this is the first item in the list. This means that removing the item involves "*prev = next" in both cases - there's no special case for updating the head pointer.

The downside is that you can't (easily) use it to traverse the structure backwards; so it's really designed to optimize the case where you only care about traversing forwards, but want to easily remove an arbitrary node.

Comment: That's really helpful to me. But I am still not quite understand:    "This means that removing the item involves "*prev = next" in both cases - there's no special case for updating the head pointer",  is there any different from "prev = next" when define *prev (not **prev)?

Comment: If prev was defined as a regular pointer, then "prev = next" would just set the prev pointer in _this_ structure to point to the next structure - it wouldn't change anything useful. But when you are removing an item from a list, you want to update the 'next' pointer in the previous structure to skip over this one, pointing to this one's next. With a regular single-* pointer, you'd use "prev->next = next" to do this. Pointers can be tricky to get your head around - for cases like this, I'd recommend drawing out some box diagrams and walking through a removal operation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, and the following link also has a good explanation. Just share it: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/trace/linkedlists.aspx

Answer (score 0):

it is not a "double pointer" as you mention. rather it is referred to as "de-referencing".

```
int x = 10;
int* prev = &x;
```

*prev is the address of variable x.

now lets say you need to pass the address of the pointer variable prev to another function named foo which accepts an address of a pointer as its parameter (pointer to a pointer).

```
void function foo(int** ptr)
{
   prinft("%p", ptr); //this would print the address of prev

   printf("%p", *ptr); //this would print the value (the address of x) contained inside address contained inside ptr.

   printf("%d", **ptr); //this would print the value (the value of x, 10) contained at the address(address of x) contained inside address (address of prev) contained inside ptr 
}
```